# Make js wait for a promise before going to next line in Nodejs ideally using ES5

Tags: javascript

I know its asked many times but I cannot make it to work in my case.

I was writing a code for IBM tool which runs the JS file using Rhino engine version 1.7R4 *(JavaScript 1.7 is default, ES5 compliance, JavaScript 1.8 generator expressions)* [See compatibility here](https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html)
The js file works on the server fine as the Rhino implementation on server executes it some synchronoous way.
It calls some built in functions which works in synchronous way. e.g. one of them brings data from database. If I try to reproduce the same functionality in my local machine the js executes asynchronously.
A sample code is below which works synchronously on server *(changing this code to await async might make it work on my machine but on server this will not work. Hence, I wont be running the same code on my machine and server)*

```
var events = new Object();

function getEvents() {
    var query = "select * from alerts.status";
    events = DirectSQL("AGG_BSS_Objectserver", query, false);
}
function processEvents() {
    // Do something with events
}
getEvents(); 
processEvents();
```

The `DirectSQL` is a built in function from server which executes synchronously and brings data in events before calling other lines of code. i.e `processEVents()` is called after obtaining results from `DirectSQL`. The above is a simplified example we are calling `DirectSQL` numerous times with complex logics.

For testing, I tried running this file on local computer using NodeJS. Since, my local machine does not have DirectSQL function. I created one in the same JS file as below. It works well but its asynchronous. i.e `processEvents()` is executed before the results are returned from `DirectSQL()`. Below is my test implementation of DirectSQL() for testing I can change it as much as I like

```
function DirectSQL(dataSrouce, query, countOnly) {
    var Sybase = require('sybase'),
        db = new Sybase(server, port, dbanem, user, pass);
    db.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        db.query(query, function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            console.log(data);

            db.disconnect();
            return data;
        });
    });
}
```

Is there any way to make DirectSQL return results in events before executing `processEvents()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for: [How is async/await transpiled to ES5](https://cmichel.io/how-is-async-await-transpiled-to-es5). At the end of the article, you have a reference to more explanations. Good luck!